# Set world coordination and camera matrix OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, matrix, opengl-es-2.0, coordinate-systems

Lately I have been trying OpenGL ES 2.0 and viewed some tutorials online, but one thing got me confused. So if I understand correctly, (0,0,0) is the center of the device and I can go 1 in each direction to get to the edge of the phone.

Now, is it possible to set my own coordinates for the world? let's say a world that is 1024x640 or something like that, and the camera matrix would be 320x480 (static, even if I change the world for different levels in the game, the camera would stay the same, making the view port the same and just the level bigger or smaller)?

I am really confused with all of the matrix thing, for now I am using

```
setLookAtM (float[] rm, int rmOffset, float eyeX, float eyeY,
float eyeZ, float centerX, float centerY, float centerZ, 
float upX, float upY, float upZ);
```

To set the view of the camera. I understand how that works.

But how would I set the world to a certain coordinate system? I want to understand it and not just "know it".

I am planning on making it a 2D game for now, so setting all the Z coordinates to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I would only use setLookAtM for 3d scenes. You need to build an orthogonal matrix and start working with that. There are several tutorials for 2D OpenGL ES 2.0 rendering out there:

For example for android a nice start would be this one: http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html

EDIT: You need to setup and ortho projection matrix that translates "world" coordinates into camera space without distorsion:

```
void buildOrthoProjectionMatrix(){
    int viewport_h = (int)_viewportHeight;
    int viewport_w = (int)_viewportWidth;

    // Calcuate view aspect factor to normalize everything to a 800x480 screen
    float view_factor_x = (float)viewport_w/(float)480;
    float view_factor_y = (float)viewport_h/(float)800;


    float [] ortho_matrix2 = {
            view_factor_x*2.f/viewport_w,           0.f,    0.f, 0.f,
            0.f, view_factor_y*2.f/viewport_h,      0.f,    0.f,
            0.f,                                    0.f,    1.f, 0.f,
            -1.f,                                   -1.f,   1.f, 1.f
    };

    this._orthoProjectionMatrix = new Matrix4(ortho_matrix2);
}
```

Then multiply your modelview matrix with this orthogonal projection matrix.

Comment: LOanks for responding, I did these tutorials already and that's where the question popped up, I know you can zoom in and out by setting the different parameters to the matrix, but how would I make 64 pixel picture "look" like  64 pixels?